# Why does only the first div respond to function?

Tags: function, html, var

I'm creating an online quiz which will consist of three different answering alternatives in three divs called #useralt. All the divs will have the same id but different content. The div with the content that is the same as the #answer-div will trigger a "Correct!" div, while the others will trigger a "Sorry"-div.

I can only get the first #useralt-div to work, the following to get numb... Can anyone help me making all three of them work?

This is the site: http://www.juliawallin.se/moviecharades/play.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#useralt").click(function(){
var correctAnswer = $('#answer').text().toLowerCase();
var givenAnswer = $('#useralt').text().toLowerCase();

var match = correctAnswer.match(new RegExp("^#moviecharades (.+)$"));
correctAnswer = match[1];

if (givenAnswer == correctAnswer)
{
     $("#correct").show("fast").delay("1000").hide("500"); //Slide Down Effect
       $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
       var el = document.createElement('div');
       el.innerHTML = $("#output")[0].innerHTML;
       document.getElementById('highscore').appendChild(el);
       var interval = 1000 * 60 * 1;
       APP.refresh(1, interval);


}
else
{
     $("#correct").hide("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
        $("#incorrect").show("500").delay("1000").hide("500");   
}
```

});
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID must be unique, you need to use class. Change your id "useralt" to class then use:

```
$(".useralt").click(function(){
var correctAnswer = $('#answer').text().toLowerCase();
var givenAnswer = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
....
...
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. So that's not going to work. Try something like:

```
<div class="useralt" id="useralt1">
<div class="useralt" id="useralt2">
<div class="useralt" id="useralt3">
```

Comment: Ok, an it's not possible to make it valid for several divs? Or how do I add several IDs to the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

From w3 schools, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

> > Specifies a unique id for the element. Naming rules: Must contain at least one character Must not contain any space characters In HTML, all
> >     values are case-insensitive